# Creating a dictionary with string as key and value as another dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

In below code, I'm trying to create a dictionary with string as key and value as another dictionary.
which is done in dictionary named dict.

print(dict)

> > {'LG_G7_Blue_64GB_R07': {'Name': 'A', 'Code': 'B', 'Sale Effective Date': 'C', 'Sale Expiration Date': 'D'}, 'Asus_ROG_Phone_Nero_128GB_R07': {'Name': 'A', 'Code': 'B', 'Sale Effective Date': 'C', 'Sale Expiration Date': 'D'}} as output.

Now using dictionaries new_dict and newest_dict trying to put values in place of 'A','B' from an excel using openpyxl.
However after 2nd iteration I'm getting the value of newest_dict as {'LG_G7_Blue_64GB_R07': **{'Name': 'Asus ROG Phone Nero 128GB', 'Code': 'Asus_ROG_Phone_Nero_128GB_R07', 'Sale Effective Date': datetime.datetime(2005, 9, 25, 0, 0), 'Sale Expiration Date': datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 27, 23, 59, 59)}**, 'Asus_ROG_Phone_Nero_128GB_R07': {'Name': 'Asus ROG Phone Nero 128GB', 'Code': 'Asus_ROG_Phone_Nero_128GB_R07', 'Sale Effective Date': datetime.datetime(2005, 9, 25, 0, 0), 'Sale Expiration Date': datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 27, 23, 59, 59)}}

while the expectation is to get -

{'LG_G7_Blue_64GB_R07': **{'Name': 'LG G7 Blue 64GB', 'Code': 'LG_G7_Blue_64GB_R07', 'Sale Effective Date': datetime.datetime(2005, 9, 25, 0, 0), 'Sale Expiration Date': datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 27, 23, 59, 59)}**, 'Asus_ROG_Phone_Nero_128GB_R07': {'Name': 'Asus ROG Phone Nero 128GB', 'Code': 'Asus_ROG_Phone_Nero_128GB_R07', 'Sale Effective Date': datetime.datetime(2005, 9, 25, 0, 0), 'Sale Expiration Date': datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 27, 23, 59, 59)}}

Please help to understand why I'm getting the second new_dict value for the key LG_G7_Blue_64GB_R07.
i.e same value for both keys LG_G7_Blue_64GB_R07 and Asus_ROG_Phone_Nero_128GB_R07.

```
new_dict = {}
newest_dict = {}
row = 2

for k,v in dict.items():


    for i,j in v.items():
        

        j = ws[j+str(row)].value


        new_dict[i] = j

        
    print(k)
    print(new_dict)
    print("------")

    newest_dict[k] = new_dict   
    print(newest_dict)
    row += 1

  
print(newest_dict)
```

In below code, I'm trying to create a dictionary with string as key and value as another dictionary.
which is done in dictionary named dict.

print(dict)

> > {'LG_G7_Blue_64GB_R07': {'Name': 'A', 'Code': 'B', 'Sale Effective Date': 'C', 'Sale Expiration Date': 'D'}, 'Asus_ROG_Phone_Nero_128GB_R07': {'Name': 'A', 'Code': 'B', 'Sale Effective Date': 'C', 'Sale Expiration Date': 'D'}} as output.

Now using dictionaries new_dict and newest_dict trying to put values in place of 'A','B' from an excel using openpyxl.
However after 2nd iteration I'm getting the value of newest_dict as {'LG_G7_Blue_64GB_R07': **{'Name': 'Asus ROG Phone Nero 128GB', 'Code': 'Asus_ROG_Phone_Nero_128GB_R07', 'Sale Effective Date': datetime.datetime(2005, 9, 25, 0, 0), 'Sale Expiration Date': datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 27, 23, 59, 59)}**, 'Asus_ROG_Phone_Nero_128GB_R07': {'Name': 'Asus ROG Phone Nero 128GB', 'Code': 'Asus_ROG_Phone_Nero_128GB_R07', 'Sale Effective Date': datetime.datetime(2005, 9, 25, 0, 0), 'Sale Expiration Date': datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 27, 23, 59, 59)}}

while the expectation is to get -

{'LG_G7_Blue_64GB_R07': **{'Name': 'LG G7 Blue 64GB', 'Code': 'LG_G7_Blue_64GB_R07', 'Sale Effective Date': datetime.datetime(2005, 9, 25, 0, 0), 'Sale Expiration Date': datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 27, 23, 59, 59)}**, 'Asus_ROG_Phone_Nero_128GB_R07': {'Name': 'Asus ROG Phone Nero 128GB', 'Code': 'Asus_ROG_Phone_Nero_128GB_R07', 'Sale Effective Date': datetime.datetime(2005, 9, 25, 0, 0), 'Sale Expiration Date': datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 27, 23, 59, 59)}}

Please help to understand why I'm getting the second new_dict value for the key LG_G7_Blue_64GB_R07.
i.e same value for both keys LG_G7_Blue_64GB_R07 and Asus_ROG_Phone_Nero_128GB_R07.

Comment: Please put your code and data into code blocks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the `new_dict` reference is stored inside `newest_dict[k]` entries and hence the last value persist in all the `newest_dict[k]` entries at the end.

**First solution** would be to create a copy of `new_dict` when you are saving.

Change

`newest_dict[k] = new_dict`

with

`newest_dict[k] = new_dict.copy()`

**Second Solution** would be to move `new_dict = {}` inside you first `for` loop.